# How can I get my TreeView icons to look good with the VSCode theme?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm writing a VSCode extension with a TreeView that has [actions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions) associated with it, and those actions have icons:

```
"contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "computerVision.removeExpression",
                "category": "CV",
                "title": "Remove",
                "icon": "resources/font-awesome/trash-can.svg"
            },
            {
                "command": "computerVision.openView",
                "category": "CV",
                "title": "Open View",
                "icon": "resources/font-awesome/window-restore.svg"
            }
        ]
        ...
}
```

But this looks like this:

[image]

Compare this to the icons in the default source control tab:

[image]

How can I get my icons to fit the current theme? I tried setting dark and light versions separately, but that didn't help.

Comment: Just for testing can you replace with `$(trash)` and see if it looks how you expect.

Comment: @Mark Yes, that looks great, and the reference is [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#icon-listing).

Comment: Were your original icons not having an unfocused look?  Was that the problem?  And can you switch to product icons?

Comment: @Mark Yes, the problem is the stark black on my icons. I needed a way to get VSCode to somehow set their color automatically (which it somehow does for sidebar tab icons). IMO using the built-in icons is a satisfactory solution.